# How to create a scatterplot of one variable comparing two groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter/xy plot of two groups against each other for a single numerical variable using ggplot.

If I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
#  condition   group     size
#1   apple_1   apple      200
#2   apple_2   apple      400
#3   apple_3   apple      600
#4    pear_1    pear      300
#5    pear_2    pear      400
#6    pear_3    pear      700
```

I want to make a scatterplot with the x-axis being the size of apples and y-axis being the size of pears, with apple_1 and pear_1 matching up to create a point, apple_2 with pear_2, and apple_3 with pear_3. This would basically result in a positively correlated scatterplot.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring `apple` and `pear` in separate columns and then it would be easier to plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(-condition) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = size, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(apple, pear)) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R option using `plot` + `unstack`

```
plot(unstack(rev(df[-1])))
```

### [image]

A `ggplot` version

```
df %>%
  select(-condition) %>%
  rev() %>%
  unstack() %>%
  ggplot(aes(apple, pear)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]